# Use an array of options in the different component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react. I think this is a very basic question, but, I was stuck over here, like ,

I have created a component which looks like ->

```
import React from 'react';

class CreateNumberOfQuestion extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let options = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.props.noc - 1; i++) {
      return "<option key=" + i + ">" + i + "</option" >
        options.push(option);
    }
    return options;
  }
}

export default CreateNumberOfQuestion;
```

So, Here, I am using this in the diff component like ,

```
<select
  className="numberDropdown selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId quesSDrop margin-left-10"
  onChange={(e) => { props.onChange(e, "count", props.data.id) }}
>
  <option disabled selected value>None</option>
  {props.noc && <CreateNumberOfQuestion noc={props.noc}/>}
</select>
```

So, I am bit confused How do I use this , like its not rendering that element, so, Here I get one number, so according to that I create number of elements, so, Is there anything that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

1- You are returning array of strings not array of JSX elements.

2- You are using return inside for loop, that will break the loop.

Push the `JSX` in `array` and return that array finally, Write it like this:

```
let options = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= this.props.noc - 1; i++) {
   options.push(<option key={i}>i</option>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select className="numberDropdown selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId quesSDrop margin-left-10" onChange={(e) => { props.onChange(e, "count", props.data.id) }}>
    <option disabled selected value>None</option>
    {props.noc && props.noc.map((noc, count) => (<option noc={noc} key={count}> {count} </option>))} 
</select>
```

Comment: If you want to make it a component rather make the entire select a component than just the option.

Comment: props.noc it can not be rendered on map, as its just a single number

Comment: oo really ? I thought it was an array. In that case you should have ```(new Array(props.noc)).map()```

Answer (score 0):

Sneak peak in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) could solve your problem :-) . 
Your component should return map aggregation of "noc's" in this case.